# Angular 5 - persist the data and avoid subsequent API calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

"@angular/core": "^5.2.0"

"rxjs": "^5.5.6"

I am new to the angular framework and currently utilizing to create an injectable service class, which will make the WebAPI call to pull the data from the backend db.

I want to persist or avoid the subsequent calls from the component which is using this service class. Because its the same data which is getting called again and again.

I feel i am making very small mistake and not able to catch it. I want to avoid the round trip for the second call. **During the first call, i want to persist the data inside the _dyndata object.**  But somehow, for every service call it is printing console.log('Fresh call') statement.

Please suggest where am i making the mistake. I want to use the inbuilt feature of angular change detection.

My service class looks like this :-

```
@Injectable()

export class DynamicDataService {

    private _dyndata: DynamicContent[];

    constructor(private _httpObj: HttpClient, private http: Http) {
    }

    headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    getdynamiccontent(): Observable<DynamicContent[]> {

        if (this._dyndata) {
            console.log('data exists!')
            return of(this._dyndata);
        }

        console.log('Fresh call');

        return this._httpObj.get<DynamicContent[]>(environment.apiHost + 'DynamiContentforPage')
            .pipe(tap(data => this._dyndata = data)
            ); 
    }
```

And the component which is consuming this service class looks like this :-

```
  import { Component, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, OnInit, Inject, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
    import { DynamicDataService } from './dynamicdata.service';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
    import { DynamicContent } from '../interfaces/IDynamicContent';

@Component({
    selector: 'CMSBlock',
    template: `<div [innerHTML]="_dynmarkup | keepHtml"></div>`,
    providers: [DynamicDataService]
})

export class DynamicDataComponent {
    public markupcollection: DynamicContent[];
    public savedmarkup: DynamicContent[];
    @Input('key') key: string;
    public _dynmarkup: any = '';

    constructor(private dynamicdataService: DynamicDataService) {
        console.log('cstor :: dynamicdata comp');
        this.getCMSData();
    }

    public getCMSData() {
        this.dynamicdataService.getdynamiccontent()
            .subscribe(px => {
                this.setUsersArray(px);
                console.log(this.markupcollection);
            });

    }

    setUsersArray(data) {
        this.savedmarkup = data;
        if (this.savedmarkup != undefined) {
            var item = this.savedmarkup.find(fx => fx.Key == this.key);
            this._dynmarkup = item.Text

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the `tap()` function for?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint into the tap callback to make sure it goes through it properly?

Comment: yeh, it works fine.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong somewhere, it works fine here https://angular5-http-client-service-demo-neerrq.stackblitz.io. Are you calling that method again from within the SAME module?

Comment: Can you please share the code for this sample ?>

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-http-client-service-demo-neerrq?file=app/app.service.ts

Comment: In my case, the page gets loaded and the DynamicDataComponent  is rendered. I am not performing any DOM element clicks..

Comment: How are you triggering the subsequent request for data? Remember that if you reload the page, the entire application is bootstrapped again @Karan

Comment: If you want to store the data for subsequent re-use and want that to survive through page reloads etc, you'd need to investigate localStorage or similar.

Comment: @MarkHughes , please suggest if we can do something during the page load stage. I have added the complete code of DynamicDataComponent.

Comment: Are you confident that this data is /never/ going to change? If so, instead of storing it in a variable (e.g. this._dynData) in DynamicDataService, store it in localStorage (you'll need to serialise it to a JSON string and de-serialise it back from a JSON string). However, that will persist indefinitely - so you need to be certain this data is never going to change before doing that.

Comment: This data could change from a different UI. That is why i do not wish to store it inside the localStorage object. But atleast it should not make multiple calls, when this service class is being used from any component.

Comment: Maybe try to read about the Service Workers, they got a cache data from API calls, and alot of features that might help you.

Comment: @Karan it won't make multiple calls if you use it from different components. But nothing persists (other than local storage) if you reload the page, so this._dyndata will get reset each time you reload the page. If you inject the service into five different components, it should only load the data from the API once.

Comment: But i am only rendering & making the call on the page load once. The component is rendered twice like this.

Comment: <div class="row bg-white">
                        <h4 class="bd-title xtr-margin pt-2 pl-2">
                            <CMSBlock key="dvimpNoticeHeader"></CMSBlock>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row bg-white">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <CMSBlock key="dvimpNoticeText" class="label label-primary"></CMSBlock>

                        </div>
                    </div>

Comment: <CMSBlock> is written in the component html page twice.

Comment: Ah - it will be a timing issue then. At the point the second one is instantiated, the first one will not YET have finished loading the data. So the _dyndata is null when the second request *starts*, so it fires off another request. To avoid that, you'd need to restructure to load the data before those components get included into the page.

Comment: can i add the delay inside , so that the first request gets finished..

Comment: Please advise . It is making me crazy..

Comment: I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: @Karan I've posted my suggestion as an answer, using a subject to create an observable is a better solution than a delay (which may or may not work depending on exact timing issues)

Comment: @Karan any progress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments on the question, it appears that you are instantiating two instances of the component, and they are both starting requests before either complete the request.

Therefore, to resolve this, you need to restructure how the service deals with the requests. I would suggest using a BehaviorSubject on the service to provide the details, as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class DynamicDataService {

    private _dyndata: BehaviorSubject<DynamicContent[]> = new BehaviourSubject<DynamicContent[]>(null);
    private _requested: boolean = false;

    constructor(private _httpObj: HttpClient, private http: Http) {
    }

    headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    getdynamiccontent(): Observable<DynamicContent[]> {
        if (!this._requested) {
            this._requested = true;
            console.log('Fresh call');
            this._httpObj.get<DynamicContent[]>(environment.apiHost + 'DynamiContentforPage')
            .subscribe(data => this._dyndata.next(data));
        } else {
            console.log('Request already made');
        }
        return this._dyndata.asObservable().pipe(filter((e) => e != null), take(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error at last line.  return this._dyndata.pipe(filter((e) => e != null).take(1));

Comment: The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'

Comment: its weird , still give me red lines underneath the filter fn

Comment: Have you imported the observable filter operator?

Comment: import { filter } from 'rxjs/operator/filter';

Comment: Please suggest where am i missing it

Comment: try adding .asObservable as I've updated the answer to reflect. I can't see any reason this shouldn't work @Karan

Comment: is it important to pipe ?

Comment: If you're using rxjs 5, you can use .filter((e) => e != null).take(1) instead of .pipe() (but that won't work when you upgrade to rxjs 6)

Comment: I tried. But again both calls result in showing the "Fresh call" in the console.

Comment: i printed this.   getdynamiccontent(): Observable<DynamicContent[]> {

        console.log(this._requested);

        if (!this._requested) {

Comment: _requested variable is always false.

Comment: Did you notice the line where this._requested is set to true? I forgot that in the initial version but it's there now ;-)

Comment: The statement does get true. It seems both the component requests appears at almost the same time.

Comment: @Karan can you add the app module ts to your question please?

Comment: I am using lazy loaded multiple modules approach in the project.

Comment: We need to see how you're registering this service - I suspect that's why it's not working @Karan as you would expect - please include the module definitions in the question.

Comment: I am only registering the DynamicDataService inside the DynamicDataComponent only.

Comment: In that case @karan I don't think it can be a singleton - see the other answer about this exact issue regarding registering services in lazy loaded modules

Answer (score 1):

you have encounter a very interesting case.

The short answer of your solution of your problem, is just to **remove** the `DynamicDataService` from your component providers and **include it**  at more appropriate place, like the `root`.

So now let's dive in the problem, when using services in angular, we are including them in the providers, of the module/component in which we want to use them (in your case the `CMSBlock`), by doing so you have access to the service and are able to call your `API` and load the desired data. But as we know the services are such thing, that **once provided** are **accessible to the hall app**, so one can ask themselves the question what will happen when we **provide multiple service with the same token**(name), or the **same service multiple times**  (which have similar effect to providing different services with the same name). The answer is that **the last one wins**, or in other words the **last** provided service will **override** the function that is provider for the service `token`.

In your case when you are using **multiple times** the `CMSBlock` component, you are providing/initializing **twice** the `DynamicDataService`, which means that each time you are calling the service, the `_dyndata` is in it's initial state, in your case it's **empty** and thanks to that a "fresh call" is made.

The best way to fix this, is to provide the service in the **closes parent module** (if you are using the service in lazy loaded module) or in the **`root`** module if you are using it **in eager loaded one**.

Edit:

Also the second call happens might happen before, the first one is completed, thanks to which the check for avaliable `_dyndata` will fail.

Here is a live demo, of the things that I talked about : [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8x797oq85j)

Comment: I don't believe this is the cause here. I think there is a single instance of the service but the call is being made twice because the _dyndata is still null when the second call starts.

Comment: Most likely is mix of both, you are tottaly right about the `_dynata=null`

Comment: I'm beginning to think you may be correct about the module loading side of how the service is registered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing is that you probably have multiple components calling `this.dynamicdataService.getdynamiccontent()` over a very short period of time creating multiple HTTP requests simultaneously before any of them completes and sets any value to `this._dyndata`.

With RxJS the best solution would be using the `publishReplay(1)` and `take(1)` operators:

```
private cachedRequest = this._httpObj.get(...).pipe(
  shareReplay(1),
  take(1),
)

getdynamiccontent() {
  return this.cachedRequest;
}
```

You don't even need to be using any intermediate variable to store the data. The `shareReplay` operator keeps always only one subscription to `this._httpObj.get(...)` while `take(1)` makes sure to properly complete the chain when the response is ready. Any subsequent subscribers will receive only one value thanks to `take(1)` that is cached inside `shareReplay(1)`.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-zanygw?file=index.ts

Comment: I will try this change and see how it goes.

Comment: oh that is beautiful :)

Comment: When i am trying this way, it is showing design time error in take fn.

Comment: return this._httpObj.get<DynamicContent[]>(environment.apiPartnerHost + 'DynamiContentforPage')
            .pipe(shareReplay(1), take(1), tap(data => this._dyndata = data)
            );

Comment: Please suggest.

Comment: Error is this :- The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'

Comment: Even i tried this statement also. And it is giving the same error.

Comment: return this._httpObj.get<DynamicContent[]>(environment.apiPartnerHost + 'DynamiContentforPage').pipe(shareReplay(1), take(1));

Comment: I am unable to understand where is the gap

Comment: @martin - after doing the import like this. import { take } from 'rxjs/operators'; i am not seeing design time error. But it is still making two web-API calls.

Comment: Do i need to mention anything else along with shareReplay and Take ?

Comment: Here's demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-zanygw?file=index.ts If this doesn't work as should then the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Please share, how to use defer and delay in my code sample.

Comment: That's only to mock the HTTP request. You'll use `http.get` instead of `defer`